# What headers does a SWF file send when requesting data from a URL

Tags: flash, actionscript, xmlhttprequest, header, flashvars

When requesting data with:

```
<param value="data-file=http://url-to-my/json.script" name="flashvars">
```

via an SWF file, what request type would "http://url-to-my/json.script" receive. It doesn't seem to be a "xmlhttprequest". Is it the same as a request from a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XmlHTTPRequest uses the same Request-Architecture as the Browser, so there would be no difference. The only thing that might differ when using a Flash-Application is the User-Agent submitted in the header of the HTTP-Request. In the above scenario I assume that a simple GET-Request is made.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

It should be a `HTTP GET` request.